# Dynamic Linq query with Contains for decimal and datetime value

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic-linq

I want to use contains() in dynamic linq query for any value. I have been able to do so only for string type. Here is the code:

```
var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
var columnName = cboCrudSearchColumn.Text.ToString();
string searchValue = txtCrudSearch.Text.ToString().ToUpper();
var truncatedData = new object();
//cadContext is an EDM.
var rawData = cadContext.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(cadContext, null);
truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Where(columnName +".Contains(@0)", searchValue ).ToList();
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = truncatedData;
```

how do I use this code for numeric and datetime value? For numeric I've tried this:

```
int x = Int32.Parse(txtCrudSearch.Text);
truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Where(columnName + ".Contains(@0)", x).ToList();
```

It says: No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Decimal'. Also I couldn't figure out what to do for datetime value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `string` has a `Contains` function, whereas `decimal` does not. I think you perhaps are wanting to call `Contains` on your `IQueryable` but it is calling it on something else?